# HTML generator that handles multiple (spoken) languages

Tags: html, internationalization, preprocessor, generator

I have a need to maintain some static HTML pages in several languages. I'm looking for a tool that will make this reasonably straightforward to maintain.

My ideal tool could take some HTML markup like this:

```
<div>
  <p>
    <langs>
      <lang lang="en">Welcome!</lang>
      <lang lang="de">Willkommen!</lang>
      <lang lang="it">Benvenuti!</lang>
    </langs>
  </p>
  <p>
    <langs>
      <lang lang="en">Where do you want to go today?</lang>
      <lang lang="de">Wo möchten Sie heute unternehmen?</lang>
    </langs>
  </p>
</div>
```

And if you ran it with the desired language codes, "de,en" it would produce:

```
<div>
  <p>Willkommen!</p>
  <p>Wo möchten Sie heute unternehmen?</p>
</div>
```

But if you ran with, "it,en" it would produce:

```
<div>
  <p>Benvenuti!</p>
  <p>Where do you want to go today?</p>
</div>
```

Where the second paragraph falls back to English as there wasn't an available translation in Italian. (The argument "it,en" indicates which languages to use in preference order.)

Anybody know of a tool that would fit the bill? I would consider something a bit more esoteric* like [HAML](http://haml-lang.com/) if it allowed something similar to the above.

* By "esoteric" I mean something where the source isn't HTML (or close to HTML) but produces HTML as the output.

Comment: the "de,en" example doesn't match the behavior or the "it,en" example in so much that no English "where do you want to go today?" text is displayed. Is this a mistake. Also, is your language content stored in a database?

Comment: The "de,en" means use "de" first, if there is no "de" then use "en". (And for more complex ones you could have more. e.g. "en-AU,en-GB,en" for instance.) My language content is in static HTML files.

Comment: Couldn't you just use JavaScript to write the contents you want? You can hide all the texts and write them on demand...

Comment: BTW. ID attribute in HTML and XML should be unique in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an [XSLT template](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) that does this.

**Edit:**
Here's an example XSL template:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:param name="desiredLang" select="'it'"/>
    <xsl:param name="defaultLang" select="'en'"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="langs">
        <xsl:variable name="desiredValue" select="./lang[@lang=$desiredLang]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="defaultValue" select="./lang[@lang=$defaultLang]"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$desiredValue">
                <xsl:value-of select="$desiredValue"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$defaultValue"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's its output:

```
<div>
    <p>Benvenuti!</p>
    <p>Where do you want to go today?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Any particular reason to downvote this? XML/XSL is an obvious choice here, the only problem with this answer is a lack of good example.

Comment: Example added. Now you see I know what I'm talking about )